# Phantomjs can't load network traffic when key down event sent

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I tried to load the network traffic from a twitter page using Phantomjs, the problem is the keypress event didn't worked. here the code (netlog.js modified)
in other words I didn't see any output with sentEvent() unlike wothout sentEvent(), i want to scroll down the twitter page to get more network traffic.

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
    system = require('system'),
    address;

if (system.args.length === 1) {
    console.log('Usage: netlog.js <some URL>');
    phantom.exit(1);
} else {
    address = system.args[1];

    page.onResourceRequested = function (req) {
        console.log('requested: ' + JSON.stringify(req, undefined, 4));
    };

    page.onResourceReceived = function (res) {
        console.log('received: ' + JSON.stringify(res, undefined, 4));
    };
    page.onLoadFinished = function(status) {
        console.log('Status: ' + status);
    };
    page.open(address, function (status) {
        if (status !== 'success') {
            console.log('FAIL to load the address');
        }else{
            page.sendEvent('keypress', page.event.key.Down);
        }
        phantom.exit();
    });
}
```

Thanks for your Help.

Comment: Usually you can call evaluate function to execute some "actions" on the twitter page. In order to load a network traffic for your Twitter account, you have to login. Here is good tutorial using PhantomJS: http://code-epicenter.com/how-to-login-amazon-using-phantomjs-working-example/

Comment: @ArtjomB. i want to load the HAR file which contains the received css, js images files from twitter. also i don't what is a keypress target, Could you please clarify this point.

Comment: So to clarify: (1) Are you seeing any output? If you do, is it the same output as without the `sendEvent()` call? (2) Are you trying to scroll down the twitter page and expect more requests to see on the network? Please [edit] your questions to properly describe what you're seeing and what you want to accomplish.

Comment: (1) no output with sentEvent(), however there is without sentEvent()
(2)yes